# Lagrangian description of fluid - approximation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, approximations

In the Lagrangian (i.e. not the Eulerian) description of fluids, the displacement field is given by $\vec{r} = \vec{r}\left(\vec{q},t\right)$ where $\vec{q}$ is the initial position of the particle. Under what circumstances can $\vec{r}$ be approximated as
$$
\vec{r} = \vec{q} + f(t)\cdot \vec{p}\left(\vec{q}\right)
$$
Are there considerations of density? Assume the fluid is pressureless.

Answer (score 0):

Since at time zero, the fluid particle must be at position $\mathbf{q}$, we must have $f(0)=0$. $f(t)$ simply scales the vector $\mathbf{p}$, the latter specifying the direction in which the fluid particle moves for all time $t\geq 0$. Therefore the expression $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{q}+f(t)\mathbf{p}$ holds so long as the motion of the fluid particle is unidirectional, while the fluid particle could accelerate or change its density. Now since fluid particles move on smooth curves, for short enough time $\delta t$, such that the distance traveled during $\delta t$ is small compared to the curvature of its path, above expression for $\mathbf{r}$ would be approximately applicable.